# C# web-form to obtain Access Token

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am new to Graph API.  I have the following code to get my access token for an app I set up already:

```
private const string _scope = "wl.skydrive_update";

private const string _clientID = "56665168-fb52-**************";

private const string _signInUrl = @"https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=https:login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf&response_type=code&scope={1}";
```

When I run this, I get: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf  window asking me to login.
HOWEVER:

I have my personal Microsoft account and Business Office 365 account.  I can get the access token through my personal account just fine BUT when I try to login (in this window login) with my business account. It keep telling me account not found. If so, then how can I (what URL) use to get response from my business account?

Any help, advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Microsoft Graph documentation page for [getting access tokens on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user).  If you register your app in the [Microsoft App registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), you can get tokens that work for consumer accounts (live, hotmail, etc.) and business accounts.

An example of the common auth experience that works for consumer and work accounts is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345